# Uncaught reference error with cookies [javascript]

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm having trouble plugging in a text field to create a cookie. There always appears to be some reference error but I can't figure out why. This seems to be a very simplified version compared to w3c but it still won't work. Does anyone know why?

```
    <div id='sandbox'>

    </div>
     Username: <input type='text' id='form'><br>
    <button onclick="createCookie">Create a cookie</button>
    <button onclick="displayCookie">Display the cookie</button>

<script>
var username = document.getElementById('form').value

function createCookie(username) {
document.cookie = "user" + "=" + username;
}

function displayCookie() {
document.getElementById('sandbox').innerHTML = document.cookie;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here, let's break it down

---

```
<node onclick="foo" />
```

Can be thought of as similar to

```
node.click = function () {
    foo
};
```

Notice how `foo` is not invoked here. You will either need to use `()` or attach it differently.

---

```
var bar = document.getElementById('form').value;
```

Will get the *Node* with *id* `form` look up it's *value* property and then take a copy and call it `bar`. This will never change again until you do `bar = ...`

---

```
function fizz(bar) {
    return bar;
}
fizz();
```

Although `bar` may have been defined before this function, that a parameter is named `bar` hides this within `fizz`, and therefore `bar` inside `fizz` can only be what is passed as the first parameter, not a `bar` from a higher scope.

---

```
var buzz = document.cookie;
```

[`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) is not a simple property as you might expect, when you try to *get* it, you'll actually be given **every** cookie.